# Why Russian/non-USA online firms never take a credit card directly?

Tags: corporate-policy, payment-gateway, payment

I've noticed it back some ten years ago, and, apparently, it's still the case today -- most online retailers in the US directly procure the information about your credit card, whereas in Russia, credit cards are mostly processed exclusively by third-party centralised payment systems (say, like Yandex.Checkout, which is actually itself a new system that's been replacing some of the older local processor-only shops).

This happens even if the retailer in question is a very established hosting provider (owns their own datacentre or two), or an ICANN-Accredited Registrar, e.g., businesses I'd actually trust (before you get to it: not just for the above reasons), compared to some random shop or periodical subscription in the US.

Comment: @drewbenn, It may have changed recently, because now everyone is "in the cloud", so, they just use PayPal.  But, basically, anyone who's not in the cloud, is still asking for CC.  SiriusXM, non-web-2.0 subscriptions of all kinds, trial offers, porn sites etc.